# Will the cost of dynamoDB read/write increase if the hashKey length is increased for a given dynamoDB-geo database?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Will the cost of dynamoDB read/write increase if the hashKey length is increased for a given dynamoDB-geo database? if not, how will increase in key length affect the app? if not how will it affect my app.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [DynamoDB docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/CapacityUnitCalculations.html):

> The total size of an item is the sum of the lengths of its attribute names and values.

This means that the length of your hash key *is* included when calculating the size of your items, which factors into the cost of using DynamoDB.

Check out this [DynamoDB calculator](https://zaccharles.github.io/dynamodb-calculator/) to see how the size of your attribute names contributes to the overall size/cost of your items.